# Php unit test problem with create customer

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Im having some problems with my unittest.
My unittest works perfect if the test is about to get anything from my datbase table.
But if I should create example a customer, im having isuses with how I should do that.

Here is an example of my getCustomer test:

Comment: where is your create customer code?

Comment: sorry i meant getSpecificCustomer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$controller = new Veosoft_Controller();
$_REQUEST = [
    'displayName' => 'meh',
    'firstname' => 'Kristian',
    'lastname' => 'Pedersen',
];

$controller->createCustomer();

// then somehow get the last insert ID?

$customer = $controller->getSpecificCustomer($customerId);
$this->assertEquals($customer->id, $customerId);
$this->assertEquals($customer->firstname, $firstName);
$this->assertEquals($customer->lastname, $lastName);
```

Of course it would be better if you just mocked the DB class itself?

Comment: Thx, It worked. Now im just need to get the last inserted ID

Comment: you could return the last insert id from the `createCustomer()` method, OR, you could get the last insert ID inside that method, and then return a customer object populated with your data and the ID